# Perform OkHttp network actions in background thread

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am using OKHttp to perform Post request to server, as follow:

```
public class NetworkManager {
    public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String post(String url, JSONObject json) throws IOException {
        try {
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("d");
            RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("m", json.getString("m"))
                    .add("d", array.toString())
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (JSONException jsone) {
            return "ERROR: " + jsone.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

and call it with:

```
NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager();
String response = manager.post("http://www.example.com/api/", jsonObject);
```

When I try to run the App, it prompts an error in the logcat:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)

With reference to other questions in SO, I added this to override the policy:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Yet I think this is unhealthy and I would like to put the `NetworkManager` actions to background. How can I do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since OkHttp supports async way too, so IMO you can refer to the following GET request sample, then apply for your POST request:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        // GET request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://google.com")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, response.body().string());
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, response.toString());
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Would recommend the OkHttp asynchronous option.

Comment: Looks promising. How do I notify the main class when the response is ready? My current logic is synchronous and directly return the response string, then the main class parses the response to do further actions.

Comment: As you see, inside `onResponse` you will do that, if you want to update UI or display Toast, you will also need `mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`. If the request inside another class (for example Utils.java), I think you should use a listener interface

Comment: You can refer to my GitHub sample project, it's a POST request. https://github.com/ngocchung/MultipartOkHttp

Comment: Great example, but only 1 question remained. I somehow need to update a variable in the class (`MainActivity`) which called the `NetworkManager`. How do I call a function on `MainActivity` ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your idea. Can you give an example?

Comment: @BNK I asked another question for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193555/okhttp-trigger-callback-in-originated-class-after-finishing-network-actions . Can you take a look? Thanks. *Sorry I'm a newbie in Android*

Comment: How to do the same in Kotlin?